# Dynamic tab bar icon/label in React Navigation V3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a tab navigator that has multiple stack navigators nested. I want to dynamically change the tab icon/tab name when I navigate to different screens in stack navigators. I know this is not possible out of the box with V3. (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html). Any suggestions to bypass this ? Tia.

Answer (score 3):

React Navigation V3 came with some breaking changes. Changing parent navigator's navigation options is only allowed from immediate children. In my case tab navigators navigation options can only be changed by the stack navigators. Not from it's screens. [Refer this link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html)

However if you want to change tab labal/tab icon based on the route you can do the following.

```js
const HomeStackNav = createStackNavigator({
  home: { screen: Home },
  Report: { screen: Report }
});

HomeStackNav.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  let navigationOptions = {};
  if (routeName === 'home') {
    navigationOptions.tabBarLabel = 'Welcome';
    navigationOptions.tabBarIcon = ({ focused }) => <WelcomeIcon focused />;
  } else {
    navigationOptions.tabBarLabel = 'Home';
    navigationOptions.tabBarIcon = ({ focused }) => <HomeIcon focused />;
  }
  return navigationOptions;
}

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeTab: HomeStackNav
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible from everywhere, because **navigationOptions** it is "static" method. Just create navigationOptions in your screen - Home (example)

// Define tab options in Home screen

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        title: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
          return <IconComponent name={'Home'} focused={focused}/>; 
        },
        tabBarLabel: "Home"
      };
    };
```

then call this method from place what you need and change data inside

```
Home.navigationOptions = {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
           return <AnotherIconComponent name={'LogOut'} focused={focused}/>; 
            }
};
```